# Save %%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%% as field value

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, import

Is there a way to get the value of **%%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%** from an import activity and save it somewhere, maybe in a DE?

I am building a dashboard (cloudpage) that will display what file is currently being processed by an automation or what has already been processed.

Assuming that I cannot add the filename as a column value in the file.

Thanks.

Comment: How about using internal API? Eg., below API gets called to get history of automation runs. when I make a get call with oauth2 bearer token, I'm getting a response with all file name. you can probably utilize this for your dashboard. 

https://mc.s7.marketingcloudapps.com/AutomationStudioFuel3/fuelapi/legacy/v1/beta/automations/automation/instance/?definition_id=a1hKR01wV0t4MGU1ZXI5S0VsMk5yQToyNTow

Comment: Thanks, but this seems like a legacy API. How are you calling this? Can you provide the exact endpoint and sample payload if any?

Comment: I know this goes back a couple of years, but did you ever find a solution to the question?  I'd like to build a DE with log entries of each file import that gets triggered.

Comment: @EricB., we ended up adding a column in the file with the filename as the value for it for us to have/get the data/filename.

Comment: You added the filename to a column in the CSV that you were importing?   Or a filename in the DataExtension and found someway to save the filename to the DE?

Comment: We added the filename to a column in the CSV that we were importing.